# Zoom in plots simultaneously in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

I tried to plot a few variables in Dymola, but when I want to zoom in on these plots, I need to zoom in on each of them manually, how could I zoom in on these plots simultaneously?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The case that makes most sense is to zoom on the x-axis which usually represents time in Dymola. You should be able to zoom all plot simultaneously by **holding down the shift-key** while doing a zooming-gesture mainly moving your mouse horizontally.

The result should look like the gif below (for the coupled-clutches demo from the MSL at `Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Examples.CoupledClutches` with the trajectories moved to separated subplots to show the effect).

[image: Zoom subplots to same time]

A similar thing can be done by moving the mouse mainly vertically. This is useful in case you don't want to change the time-scale of the plot.

**One addition:**

Another neat feature that is actually not known very well thing, using the **Alt-key** in a similar way as described above. This will result in synched zooming for time AND adjusting the amplitude in all subplots, an example:

[image: Zoom subplots to same time with auto-amplitude]